# Separating UI event listening from a Part in Eclipse RCP: how to do it properly?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a huge `Part` source code I have to touch at 1 place. It is violating a lot of principles so I would like to extract at least the function I had to modify which is a `@UIEventTopic` handler. There are no tests and I would like to add them here so I know I do not break existing functionality.

I would like to move away from this:

```
public class MyPart {
  ...

  @Inject
  @Optional
  public void event(@UIEventTopic(EVENT) EventParam p) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To something like this:

```
public class MyPart {
  ...
}

public class MyEventHandler { 
  @Inject
  @Optional
  public void event(@UIEventTopic(EVENT) EventParam p, MyPart part) {
    ...
  }
}
```

With the Eclipse DI I see no easy way of creating an instance of the handler class. It cannot be a `@Singleton` because it is a `Part` which can have multiple instances, and adding the handler to the `IEclipseContext` in the `@PostConstruct` is ugly because it adds a circular dependency between the part and the handler. Is there a magic how I can enforce the instantiation through the e4xmi files, or some alternative way?

My current solution is to extract purely the functionality to a utility bean and return the data and set it on the part, but this is also something not too nice (requires a lot of additional null-checks, ifs, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that I understand your question, however, this is how I would proceed:

**Extract Delegate**

Move the code in `event()` to the `MyEventHandler` so that `MyClass` fully delegates the event handling

```java
public class MyPart {
  @Inject
  @Optional
  public void event( @UIEventTopic(EVENT) EventParam param ) {
    new MyEventHandler().handleEvent( this, param );
  }
}

class MyEventHandler { 
  void handleEvent(MyPart part, EventParam param) {
    // all code from event() goes here
  }
}
```

This should be a safe-enough refactoring to do without having tests - and in the end, you don't have a choice as there are no tests.

**Ensure the Status Quo**

Now I would write tests for `handleEvent()`, mocking the required methods of `MyPart` and thus make sure that I won't break existing behavior.

**Implement new Feature**

After that I would be able to make the desired changes to `MyEventHandler::handleEvent` in a test driven manner.

**Clean Up**

Then I would extract an interface from `MyPart` that has only those methods required for `MyEventHandler` to do its work. If said interface gets too big, it would indicate that there is more refactoring left to do.

Comment: Hi Rüdiger, Yeah, thx a lot. In the end we ended up with a similar situation - expecte passing the part because mocking would have made the tests a bit bloated. So we rather created a result object and I'm testing that. Thx for the insights.